# Adding a default Razor page/index to a .Net Core API project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

I'd like to add a default page/index page that is Razor (cshtml) to my .NET Core 6 project.
I've created the `wwwroot` directory inside my project, and added a Razor page named `index.cshtml` inside of it. In it, I've added some HTML and added `@page "/"` to signify that it should be the root.

Because it is an API project, in my launchSettings.json file, I've commented out the `launchurl` so that it is no longer pointing to swagger:

[image]

In my Program.cs, I've tried both including and excluding the following code (I think it should be excluded since cshtml is not a static file):

```
app.UseStaticFiles( new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot" ) )
} );
```

However, the end result is the same - when I run my API locally, my browser opens to a blank page. Is there something I've missed? I tried adding a static page (index.html) and it *did* work, but I need the functionality of a Razor page. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to add a default page/index page that is Razor (cshtml) to my
> .NET Core 6 project.

I have a suggestion like below, hope it can help.

1.In Program.cs, add below code:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
...
app.MapRazorPages();
```

2.Then add a Pages folder like:

[image]

3.And in the Index.cshtml add `@page "/"`

4.And  commented out below code in your aunchSettings.json file as yours:

```
"launchUrl": "swagger",
```

5.result:
[image]

Comment: This helped a lot. The 2 key changes of your code snipped in 1, and renaming my `wwwroot` folder to `pages` made it work. Thank you.